# Making Google direct users to region-specific website or subdomain

Tags: google-ads-api, google-search

I have a good, short website name like mysite.fr.
It's a website for my real shop (not an online shop).

I have 2 shops. These shops are located in 2 different cities, relatively far away from each other.

I could

```
1) make one website with 2 subdomains like

    paris.mysite.fr
    marseille.mysite.fr

2) make 2 new domains like

    mysite-paris.fr
    mysite-marseille.fr

    But that would mean that I can't use my great, short URL anymore.
```

If option 1 is preferred, I would like to ask how I could properly teach Google what to show each Google Search user. I think it's contraproductive if I have to ask the user to choose the correct city to get to the appropriate shop.

I know that this is possible when using Google Ad campaigns, but I don't know of a way to do that for the common Google search.

Or is option 2 preferred anyways because option 1 is too error-prone?

Thank you.

Comment: why do you want to do it? pricing? different products? If nothing is changing I don't see a reason to use a subdomain and managing it

Comment: @AnkDasCo Yes, different pricing and different products.

Comment: `I think it's contraproductive if I have to ask the user to choose the correct city to get to the appropriate shop` a lot of websites are actually like that, it's not *counterproductive* at all :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many solutions you could use from the top of my mind I'm thinking about this flow.

First you need the user address:

- Could be based on user input (asking for his address) in a text box like the typical food delivery landing page
- Could be based on some "plugin" like [google maps geolocation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geolocation/intro) that tells you which is the place he is connecting from (usually it tells you street and such)

Then you need to basically locate to which store he is closer to

Then you need to decide which URL solution to use.

- [Proposal] You could also move it to `mysite.fr/paris` or `mysite.fr/marseille` (sometimes this is better seo speaking, and also simpler when it comes to management) **and you keep that amazing site name as the main protagonist** as you were stating

Then you need to basically redirect him to the page to the store he was closer to.

In any case, I've been working in several sites that had that "change items based on address logic" and you can PM me for more info :)

Also there are ways in google Adwords in which you can basically put an advertisement only for certain keywords, regions and such, and in that case that is the option you are looking for. You should just create 2 rules, (one per region) and basically just display the adds to the people that are inside the area. This is an example of how the configuration you should put looks like in google Adwords. (*It's really simple*)

[image: Image of the places selector]

And this is how the add would look like in the google search or other channels depending on the target you select

[image: Add example]

See my LinkedIn if you want to contact me https://www.linkedin.com/in/alejandro-vales/

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest the first way you mentioned and I guess you could use Radius around a location in Google Ads:

**Radius targeting** (also known as proximity targeting or "Target a radius") allows you to choose to show your ads to customers within a certain distance from your business, rather than choosing individual cities, regions, or countries.

**Selecting a radius**

When you target a radius, it's worth keeping in mind that selecting a small radius could mean that your ads might only show intermittently or not at all. That’s because small targets might not meet our targeting criteria.

1. From the page menu on the left, click Locations.
2. Click the name of the campaign you wish to edit.
3. Click the blue pencil icon, then select Radius.
4. In the search box, enter the address of the location you'd like to use for the center of the radius. Enter the radius that you'd like to target and select a unit of measurement from the drop-down menu.
5. Check the map to make sure you're targeting the correct area. When you're ready, click Save to add the radius target.
6. Click Save.

The documentation can be found [here](https://support.google.com/google-ads/answer/1722043?hl=en).

A Complete tutorial :[The Complete Guide to AdWords Location Targeting](https://blog.tryadhawk.com/google-adwords/geo-targeting/).

Comment: Thank you, I'm already doing that for Google Ads, but I was looking for a way for organic search.